# Need count of negative values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need total count of negative values in a dataframe. i am able to get for an array but unable to find for DataFrame. for array i am using below code can any one suggest me how to get the count for below DataFrame.

```
sum(n<0 for n in numbers)
```

Below is my dataframe and expected result is 4

```
  a  b  c  d
   -3 -2 -1  1
   -2  2  3  4
    4  5  7  8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am able to get for an array but unable to find for DataFrame

It's possible to flatten the DataFrame to use functions that operation on 1D arrays. So if you're okay with that (likely to be slower than EdChum's answer):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-3, -2, 4], 'b': [-2, 2, 5], 'c': [-1, 3, 7], 'd': [1, 4, 8]})
>>> df.values
array([[-3, -2, -1,  1],
       [-2,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  7,  8]])
>>> df.values.flatten()
array([-3, -2, -1,  1, -2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  7,  8])
>>> sum(n < 0 for n in df.values.flatten())
4
```

Comment: This is faster for small dfs but it doesn't scale well for larger dfs, I've included timings in my answer

Answer (score 28):

You can call `.lt` to compare the df against a scalar value and then call `sum` twice (this is because it sums row-wise first)

```
In [66]:
df.lt(0).sum()

Out[66]:
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    0
dtype: int64
```

Call `sum` again to sum the `Series`:

```
In [58]:
df.lt(0).sum().sum()

Out[58]:
4
```

You can also convert the boolean df to a 1-D array and call `np.sum`:

```
In [62]:
np.sum((df < 0).values.ravel())

Out[62]:
4
```

**Timings**

For a 30K row df:

```
In [70]:
%timeit sum(n < 0 for n in df.values.flatten())
%timeit df.lt(0).sum().sum()
%timeit np.sum((df < 0).values.ravel())

1 loops, best of 3: 405 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 770 µs per loop
```

The np method wins easily here ~525x faster than the loop method and ~4x faster than the pure pandas method

Answer (score 5):

```
count = (df < 0).sum().sum()
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following. Might not be the best way to go about it.

```
negatives = len(df.loc[(df.a < 0)]) + len(df.loc[(df.b < 0)] + 
            len(df.loc[(df.c < 0)] + len(df.loc[(df.d < 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

EdChum's solution is very good, but I'd like to add another simple and acceptable solution that uses the `pd.DataFrame.agg` method, which is very commonly used and should therefore be easy to remember:

```py
# Set up dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-3, -2, 4],
                   'b': [-2, 2, 5],
                   'c': [-1, 3, 7],
                   'd': [1, 4, 8]})
```

The `pd.DataFrame.agg` method to aggregate each row or column (columns by default) into a Series object. Then you can aggregate the series to get a scalar:

```py
# Count all negative values in a dataframe.
df.agg(lambda x: sum(x < 0)).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> 4
```